# What Lore Changed Between Editions?

Tags: lore, edition-comparison, eclipse-phase

Now that the second edition of Eclipse Phase is out, I would like to know what bits of lore are *different* in second edition. I know most of it was *meant* to stay intact, but that doesn't mean that there aren't changes (intended or accidental) that I may not be noticing.

One example I noticed is differences in economics of morphs caused by changing speeds of morph production; another is an implication that in 2e, Hexanewts are not all that similar anatomically to Amphibs. **What are the other lore changes, especially ones with far-spanning implications?**

Comment: There is a discussion of this topic on Eclipse Phase's forums, would you like to turn them into an answer? https://eclipsephase.com/2n-edition-lore-differences

Comment: @ZwiQ This *is* a helpful link, and helps me with choosing which parts to pay the most attention to when acquainting myself with the new book, but link-*only* answers are not a good fit for the stack. A summary of the changes found throughout the posts would be perfect, though.

Comment: I could copy and paste a reasonable looking list, but unfortunately I am not experienced enough to assess the veracity of the differences on the page that I linked. That is why I asked whether you would like to turn them into a self-answer. :-)

Comment: Vicky, I think @ZwiQ was suggesting you might want to consult that link and self-answer your question - the question was "would you like to" not "would you like me to".